# Bitwise AND operator not working for hexadecimal inputs

Tags: c

I am making a program in C to grab the first 4 bits of an unsigned number. I'm not sure why, but every time I enter a hexadecimal value for the parameter of that unsigned number (the parameter is also called "number"), it returns a result of 0. I have included a hexadecimal value in main that is SUPPOSED to return 9—since the first four bits in binary are 1001—to illustrate this. What am I doing wrong that is making the bitwise operator AND not working?

```
    unsigned int returnedBits(unsigned int number, int bits, int startingPos) { 
    
    int theNumberShifted = (number >> (startingPos));
    int theNumberOfBits = ((1 << bits) - 1);
        
      return theNumberOfBits & theNumberShifted; 
      
    } 
      
    // Driver code 
    int main() 
    { 
        int unsigned number = 0x1264c000, k = 4, p = 0; 
        printf("The extracted number is %d",  
                   returnedBits(number, k, p)); 
        return 0; 
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect ?

Comment: I am expecting it to return "9." I thought that all bitwise operations are done in binary, so the first 4 bits should be "1001" from the original hexadecimal number 0x1264c000

Comment: You know about endianness ?

Comment: @Ôrel endianess is irrelevant here, these are all logical operations that will behave the same regadless

Comment: OK I think the confusion here is what you mean by 'first' four bits'. You seem to mean the first non zero most significant bits. In your case that is 101 = 9. Thats a much tougher problem. What you have is code that reads the four least significant bits. And BTW has nothing to do with hex or decimal

Comment: no it supposed to return 0 as bits from 4 to 7 inclusive are all zeroes.

Comment: This is really not clear what is the first four bits on `0b00110000000000000000000000001111`  `0011`, `1100` or `1111` ?

Comment: op wants 1100, first non zero most sig

Comment: @bleplop can you confirm ?

Comment: look at his comment on yr answer

Comment: Based on your description in various comment, you want to get the `bits` most significant bits where the high bit is nonzero.  This suggests that the `startingPos` parameter is irrelevant since it is trimming off the least significant bits.  So in your example the desired results would be 9 for any value for `startingPos` from 0 to 25.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior:

```
0x1264c000 &
       0xf
__________
         0
```

Try with k = 16

```
0x1264c000 &
    0xffff
__________
    0xc000
```

with k=24

```
0x1264c000 &
  0xffffff
__________
  0x64c000
```

Comment: I thought the comparison would occur in binary since everything in memory in C is binary. What exactly needs to be added to the program to have it grab the first four bits in binary of that original hexadecimal number, and then return it as a normal decimal?

Comment: @bleplop you code is correct and doing what you want. Maybe we are missing what you mean by 'first' do you mean the most or least significant?

Comment: I guess I mean "most significant" I am trying to grab the first "1011" in 000000000000101100000110010000010010

Comment: You should not think with bits but only with bytes

Comment: @bleplop That binary number you give is 0xb06412 in hex, not  0x1264c000.  How did you come up with that?

Comment: There is more than 32 bits in the binary you give....

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code.

```
unsigned int returnedBits(unsigned int number, int bits, int startingPos) {
    number <<= startingPos;
    unsigned int maskbit = (1 << 31);
    while ((number & maskbit) == 0) 
        number <<= 1;
    return number >> (32 - bits);
}

// Driver code 
int main()
{
    unsigned int number = 0x1264c000, k = 4, p = 0;
    printf("The extracted number is %d",
        returnedBits(number, k, p));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We don't know the order of bits only the order of bytes

Comment: @Ôrel what do you mean? Are you saying that C doesnt define the order of bits. It certainly defines how they behave even if it doesnt say what they look like in memory.

Comment: Yep bits are not adressable, only bytes are.

Comment: OP wants the first n most significant bits, a significantly harder problem